# Differentiating parametric equations

Tags: derivatives, parametric

The parametric equations of a curve are $$ x = t + \cos(t)$$$$ y= \ln(1+\sin(t))$$

where $-\frac {1}{2}\pi < t <\frac {1}{2}\pi$

$i) $ Show that $\frac{dy}{dx} = \sec (t)$

I got that $\frac{dx}{dt} = 1 -\sin(t)$ and $\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac {\cos(t)} {1 + \sin(t)}$, I don't get the correct answer when I do $\frac {dy}{dx} = \frac {dx}{dt} * \frac {dt}{dy}$, where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You introduced $\frac {dy}{dx} = \frac {dx}{dt} * \frac {dt}{dy}$ which is wrong. Well, we have 
$$\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dx}&=\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}\\
&=\frac{\frac{\cos t}{1+\sin t}}{1-\sin t}\\
&=\frac{\cos t}{1+\sin t}\cdot\frac{1}{1+\sin t}\\
&=\frac{\cos t}{1-\sin^2t}\\
&=\frac{\cos t}{\cos^2t}\\
&=\frac{1}{\cos t}\\
&=\sec t
\end{align}$$

Comment: The following question to this is:

Hence find the x-coordinates of the points on the curve at which the gradient is equal to 3. Give your answers correct to 3 significant figures.

I got $t = cos^{-1}\frac {1}{3}$, but how do I found the $x$ solutions?

Comment: @Riduan Gonzalez What about using the formula $x=t+\cos t$?

Comment: I used it and I get $x = 1.33..$, the solutions that are correct are: $x = 1.56$ and $x = -0.898$, how do I get them?